# Can't use igraph within r script, when starting from command line

Tags: r, igraph

I have written an R script, which I run from R using the command `source("script.r")`. It works perfectly.

However, when I try to run the exact same script from command line using either one of the commands: `Rcript script.r`, `R --vanilla < script.r` or `R CMD BATCH script.r` I get the error:
"Error in library(igraph): there is no package called 'igraph'"

If I remove the line from the script and run it without the command `library(igraph)`, then I get the error that function `graph.frame.data` could not be found, which is a function of igraph.
The script that runs from the Rstudio, does not contain the line `library(igraph)` and I don't get such an error.

When trying to inform myself about problems of running igraph from a script I have not found any additional information.

Some more information: I am building a graph from multiple files and then doing calculations using the igraph library on that created graph. This is executed within a loop, that goes through all (specific) directories. Output is written out into a file using `cat(..)`.

Thanks for the help in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The igraph library was not installed to the default lib position.
Using the command `library("igraph", lib.loc="..igraph.location..")` solved the issue.

The library was loaded and the execution of the script proceeded without problems.